# React DND drop position flickers by 4 - 6 pixels in some browsers

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am using [React-DND](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/) in my project. I cannot place the drop component in exact position. e.g: if i try to place it in x:20 y:20 from any point, the final position of component after dropped is x:14 y:16. While in some browsers and OS this doesn't seem to be the issue. Any idea what is causing it and how to solve?